# Group data based on unique ID and then pasting it onto the same row

Tags: r

I have a subset of my data :

```
a3 <- structure(list(Employee.Number = c("10034", "10034", "10034"), 
               Employee.Full.Name = c("Wayne, Bruce", "Wayne, Bruce", 
                                      "Wayne, Bruce"), Case.No = c("78582", "87758", "87758"), 
               Diagnoses.No = c("1", "2", "1"), Diagnosis.Medical.Code.Code = c("151.9", 
                                                                                "285.9", "V70-V82"), Diagnosis.Medical.Code.Description = c("Stomach, unspecified", 
                                                                                                                                            "Anemia, unspecified", "Tummy AChe"
                                                                                )), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

How would I go about grouping the Case.No and if the "Diagnoses.No" equals 2 (the actual data has numbers >2), then the last 3 columns will be pasted onto the column of the same Case.no with the Diagnoses.No with 1 with the original column removed?

Desired results:

```
10034  Wayne, Bruce  78582  1  151.9    Stomach, unspecified   NA


10034  Wayne, Bruce  87758  1  V70-V82  Tummy AChe 2  285.9    Anemia, unspecified
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to reshape multiple value columns from long to wide format.

One possible approach is to use the `reshape()` function in base R:

```
reshape(a3, v.names = c("Diag.MC.Code", "Diag.MC.Descr"), timevar = "Diag.No", 
        idvar = c("Emp.No", "Emp.Full.Name", "Case.No"), direction = "wide")
```

> ```
>   Emp.No Emp.Full.Name Case.No Diag.MC.Code.1      Diag.MC.Descr.1 Diag.MC.Code.2     Diag.MC.Descr.2
> 1  10034  Wayne, Bruce   78582          151.9 Stomach, unspecified           <NA>                <NA>
> 2  10034  Wayne, Bruce   87758        V70-V82           Tummy AChe          285.9 Anemia, unspecified
> ```

Please, note that column names have been renamed (shortened) to make the result table fit on the page.

#### Data

```
a3 <- structure(list(Emp.No = c("10034", "10034", "10034"), Emp.Full.Name = c("Wayne, Bruce", 
"Wayne, Bruce", "Wayne, Bruce"), Case.No = c("78582", "87758", 
"87758"), Diag.No = c("1", "2", "1"), Diag.MC.Code = c("151.9", 
"285.9", "V70-V82"), Diag.MC.Descr = c("Stomach, unspecified", 
"Anemia, unspecified", "Tummy AChe")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

# abbreviate column names to make result table fit on page
a3 <- setNames(a3, c("Emp.No", "Emp.Full.Name", "Case.No", "Diag.No", 
                     "Diag.MC.Code", "Diag.MC.Descr"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The presentation is a bit different to what you wanted but see if it works for you.

`tidyverse` solution:

```
# function to concartinate columns
cat_function <- function(df){
  map_df(df, ~paste(unlist(.), collapse = " / "))
}

a3 %>% 
  group_by(Employee.Number, Employee.Full.Name, Case.No) %>% 
  nest %>% 
  transmute(Employee.Number, Employee.Full.Name, Case.No, 
             res = map(data, cat_function)) %>% 
  unnest
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the output you want, but I think this script could help. It uses data.table package:

```
library(data.table)
a3<-data.table(a3)

a2 <-a3[Diagnoses.No==2,list(Employee.Number,Employee.Full.Name,Case.No, 
                             x=paste0(Diagnoses.No, ' ', Diagnosis.Medical.Code.Code), Diagnosis.Medical.Code.Description),]

a1 <-a3[Diagnoses.No==1,]

a3 <- merge(a1,a2, by=c('Employee.Number','Employee.Full.Name','Case.No'), all.x=T)
a3 <- a3[,list(Employee.Number,Employee.Full.Name,Case.No,Diagnosis.Medical.Code.Code, 
            Diagnosis.Medical.Code.Description.x= paste0(Diagnosis.Medical.Code.Description.x,' ',x),
            Diagnosis.Medical.Code.Description.y)]
```

The output is similar to your request:

```
> a3
   Employee.Number Employee.Full.Name Case.No Diagnosis.Medical.Code.Code Diagnosis.Medical.Code.Description.x Diagnosis.Medical.Code.Description.y
1:           10034       Wayne, Bruce   78582                       151.9              Stomach, unspecified NA                                 <NA>
2:           10034       Wayne, Bruce   87758                     V70-V82                   Tummy AChe 2 285.9                  Anemia, unspecified
```

Hope it helps!